# How can i have two models in one serializer in django

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I created API Views using django rest framework, I have a model which icsconsist of list of states in it and it associates with another model called country by the help of country(which consist of list countries) foreignkey I am trying to insert new state  **(for example: Cherries under category of sweets, Burger under category of Junkfood, exactly as "State under category of countries")** but i am getting only state input form and not getting countries to select and associate,

```
## Heading ##
#model code---
class states(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    country = models.ForeignKey(countries, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

#serializers code---
class StatesDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = states
        fields= '__all__'
        depth = 1

#viewsets code ------
class StateCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = states.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StatesDetailSerializer
```

I had attached a image, teach me how can i get countries data and to associate with states.how can i get list of countries to select and tag to states
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY30F.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extend your serializer to include country field like this

```
class StatesDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    country = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=countries.objects.all()) 

    class Meta:
        model = states
        fields= ( 'country', ** plus all the fields you want **)
        depth = 1
```

note: don't use `__all__` for the fields. It is always better to explicitly state which fields you want to serialize ( to avoid potential vulnerabilities in your application)

Comment: Dear Enthusiast martin thank you very much, it worked